# Is space considered a metacharacter in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, escaping, character

I have searched for the list of metacharacters in Bash but space is not enlisted.
I wonder if I'm right by assuming that space is the "token separation character" in Bash, since it not only works as such with Shell programs or builtins but also when creating an array through compound assignment - quotes escape spaces, just like they do most other metacharacters.
They cannot be escaped by backslashes, though.

Parameters are passed to programs and functions separated by spaces, for example.
Can someone explain how (and when) bash interprets spaces? Thanks!

I've written an example:

```
$ a=(zero one two)

$ echo ${a[0]}
```

$ zero

```
$ a=("zero one two")

$ echo ${a[0]}
```

$ zero one two

Comment: What source did you use that *didn't* list a space as a metacharacter?

Comment: @chepner: it would be hard to tell after all this time, but I have a faint memory that it might have been this one: http://www.angelfire.com/mi/genastorhotz/reality/computers/linux/bashmetachars.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the man page:

```
metacharacter
      A character that, when unquoted, separates words.  One of the following:
      |  & ; ( ) < > space tab
                     ^^^^^
```

Comment: Also, spaces *can* be escaped by backslashes. Try `a=(zero\ one\ two); echo "${a[0]}"` -- it'll print `zero one two`.

Comment: Yup; in `bash` parlance, `\ ` is a quoted space, the same as `' '` and `" "`.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Posix shell specification for [Token Recognition](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_03), any shell (which pretends to be Posix-compliant) should interpret whitespace as separating tokens:

7. If the current character is an unquoted `<newline>`, the current token shall be delimited.
8. If the current character is an unquoted `<blank>`, any token containing the previous character is delimited and the current character shall be discarded.

Here `<blank>` refers to the character class **blank** as defined by `LC_CTYPE` at the time the shell starts. In almost all cases, that character class consists precisely of the space and tab characters.

It's important to distinguish between the shell mechanism for recognizing tokens, and the use of `$IFS` to perform word-splitting. Word splitting is performed (in most contexts) after brace, tilde, parameter and variable, arithmetic and command expansions. Consider, for example:

```
$ # Setting IFS does not affect token recognition
$ bash -c 'IFS=:; arr=(foo:bar); echo "${arr[0]}"'
foo:bar
$ # But it does affect word splitting after variable expansion
$ bash -c 'IFS=: foobar=foo:bar; arr=($foobar); echo "${arr[0]}"'
foo
```

Comment: Thanks, you answered my second question in your very informative answer.

Comment: I'll try to remember to upvote it once I have enough rep score. Although based upon the text found in the manuals the other answers have guided me to Bash might not be completely POSIX compliant in regard to blanks, as the GNU manual states that <blank> is "a space or tab character".

Comment: @larry: difficult to tell, since in every common locale, LC_CTYPE recognizes precisely space and tab as blank. (eg. `man isblank`: "isblank():  checks for a blank character; that is, a space or a tab".) I should have mentioned that.

Comment: I guessed that actually, but still, the two standards can conflict considering the definitions only. I didn't mean to say you provided inaccurate information or something.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. From the Bash Reference Manual's [Definitions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Definitions) section:

> #### blank
>
> A space or tab character.
>
> …
>
> #### metacharacter
>
> A character that, when unquoted, separates words. A metacharacter is a **blank** or one of the following characters: ‘`|`’, ‘`&`’, ‘`;`’, ‘`(`’, ‘`)`’, ‘`<`’, or ‘`>`’.